# Uninstall Site Collection Features not found error. What's the physical path for them?

Tags: deployment, feature

I want to uninstall some features of the site collection on my server.

These features are on my site collection and of site or web scope. On the Sharepoint "Site Settings" -> "Manage site features" or "Site collection features" I can find them, activate or deactivate them. But in the `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES` I cannot find them.

I tried the following methods:

1. Using stsadm `uninstallfeature` operation with the feature id I get the "Feature with Id ... is not installed in this farm" error.
2. Using Powershell I can see them by `Get-SPFeature -Site/-Web` when they are activated. But when I use `Uninstall-SPFeature -Identity` with the Id it cannot find the feature again.
3. Using WssRemoveFeatureFromSite tool, I can successfully remove features, but not uninstalled, because after the action, they are still there, just deactivated.
4. Using the FeatureAdmin tool, the same as the third one.

Does "remove" means "deactivate" actually?
And anyone knows how to uninstall them? Thanks in advance!

Ps: I managed to make them disappear in the site and site collection features list by deactivating (and then delating) the solutions I used to deploy them in "Site Settings" -> "Galleries" -> "Solutions".

But Still, the feature is still there somewhere. Because when I try to redeploy (I want to uninstall it because a mysterious error persists) it with the same name, I get a "Ambiguous match found" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make them disappear in the site and site collection features list by deactivating  the SOLUTION I used to deploy them in "Site Settings" -> "Galleries" -> "Solutions". Deactivating the solution means deactivating features too. After the deactivation of the solution, the gray "Delete" button for the sollution is enabled. Then delating the solution help uninstall the feature from the site collection.

The "Ambiguous match found" I encountered was caused by errors in my code. It has nothing to do with not completely deleting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Using stsadm uninstallfeature operation with the feature id I get the
>   "Feature with Id ... is not installed in this farm" error.

Use this

```
stsadm -o uninstallfeature

   -filename <file name>

   -name <feature folder>

   -id <feature ID>

   [-force]
```

Make sure you use force attribute and don't delete feature folder from 12 hive manually at all as other wise it will corrupt your site collection and will take longer to fix it. For more information check this [MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262976%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

also for deactivating you can use

```
stsadm -o deactivatefeature

   -filename

   -name <feature folder>

   -id <feature ID>

   [-url] <URL name>

   [-force]
```

> Does "remove" means "deactivate" actually? And anyone knows how to
>   uninstall them? Thanks in advance!

I never heard about anything like remove feature, can you tell where did you find it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The "remove" appeared in the Feature Admin tool http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/. What it did was just deactivating features :) for the stsadm, when I add force the feature is still not found. Although I finally solved the problem, I do want to know how to use stsadm with non-farm features...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did a nono ;) you uninstalled the feature without disabling it first making it stuck on the site even tho its removed!

You need to use this tool as it looks like your features are stuck within the site, this will find and clean faulty features:

> The Feature Admin Tool finds faulty FeatureDefinitions and cleanly
>   uninstalls them. It finds feature remainders in sites,
>   SiteCollections, WebApps and in the Farm, caused e.g. by forcefully
>   uninstalled Features from a farm without deactivating them before.
>   These faulty features, never visible, cause errors. The Feature Admin
>   Tool is able to identify them and remove them. Very useful for
>   migrations e.g. from 2007 to 2010 or from Enterprise to Standard.
>
> Also, uninstall, (bulk) deactivate or (bulk) activate features with
>   any scope farm wide. Ideal, for activating or deactivating features in
>   large farms with many sites and/or SiteCollections.

http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, althought as I mentioned in my question, the Feature Admin Tool didn't help me with the particular feature I wanted to remove, it did removed some other faulty features :)